# Failed to initialize build 'vsphere-iso': builder type not found: vsphere-iso

Tags: vsphere, packer

I'm having issues on MacOSX with a Packer Plugin that doesn't seem to be recognized. I've installed it using multiple methods. Including creating a `~/.packer.d/plugins` directory and moving the plugin there and granting `execute` permissions.

This is the plugin:
[packer-builder-vsphere](https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/packer-builder-vsphere/releases)

I'm running a very simple packer build just to test it and I get the error:
`Failed to initialize build 'vsphere-iso': builder type not found: vsphere-iso`

I've also tried adding it to the same directory as packer `/usr/local/bin/` AND I've tried running it from the `Current Running Directory` as well. None of these methods are working and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /full-path-to-the-plugin/packer*`?

Comment: ```drwxrwxrwx@ 19 mrsmi25  US\Domain Users  608 Nov  9 09:59 packer-builder-vsphere-2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the plugin executable is wrong, it should be `packer-builder-vsphere-iso` and not include the version.

Comment: OH thank you! This is something I can handle. ```Failed to initialize build 'vsphere-iso': error initializing builder 'vsphere-iso': fork/exec /usr/local/bin/packer-builder-vsphere-iso: no such file or directory```

Comment: I got `Failed to initialize build 'vsphere-iso': error initializing builder 'vsphere-iso': fork/exec /Users/me/.packer.d/plugins/packer-builder-vsphere-iso: exec format error` :-(

Comment: Did you add the wrong binary, or failed to make it excitable?